# JQueryMobile: page with data (from ajax) doesn't change

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

```
function returnQueryResultJson(url,callback) {
   return  $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            callback(response);
        }
    });
}

function showCategory(url,hash, options) {
    var cat = hash.replace(/.*category=/, "");
    if (cat == '#page1') {
        cat = '';
    }
    var a = returnQueryResultJson('http://www.placetowebservice.nl/categories.php?category=' + cat,function(res) {
        var
            category = res,
            pageSelector = hash.replace(/\?.*$/, ""),
            $page = $(pageSelector),
            $header = $page.children(":jqmData(role=header)"),
            $content = $page.children(":jqmData(role=content)"),
            markup = '<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b">';
            var cItems = category;
            var headername = category.name;
            var numItems = cItems.length;
            if (cat == '') {
                markup = '<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b" style="min-height:100%;">';
            }
            for (var i=0;i<numItems;i++) {
                markup += '<li><a href="#category-item?category=' + cItems[i].id + '" data-rel="close"><h3>' + cItems[i].title + '</h3><p>' + cItems[i].description + '</p></a></li>';
            }
            markup += "</ul>";
            $header.find("h1").html(headername);
            $content.html(markup);
            $page.page();
            $content.find(":jqmData(role=listview)").listview();
            options.dataUrl = url;
            options.changeHash = true;
            options.reloadPage = true;
            console.log($page);
            $.mobile.changePage($page, options);
        //}
    });

}
$(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function(e,data) {
    if (typeof data.toPage === "string") {
        var
            uz = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(data.toPage),
            re = /^#category-item/,
            re2 = /^#page1/
            ;
        if (uz.hash.search(re) !== -1 || uz.hash.search(re2) !== -1) {
            showCategory(uz.href,uz.hash,data.options);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

I have got this code, and it works pretty good (first time). I first load a page with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.mobile.changePage('index.html#page1',{ dataUrl: "index.html#page1?category=", transition: "fade" });
});
```

It works, it loads the ajax-data in the page with id="page1".

Then I click on a link (category 1) and it shows the second page (with id="category-item") and fills it with the right data (category 1: sub 1, category 1: sub 2). Then I go back and it shows the categories again.

Now the problem appears, when I click on the next category (category 2). When I go to that page, it gives the right data from ajax (I used console.log to check this), but the data on the screen remains the data from category 1.

So the content from the first category you click on remains, even though you afterwards went to another category. It will remain showing the category you first clicked on.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add `refresh` here `$content.find(":jqmData(role=listview)").listview('refresh')`.. Remove `.ready()` it's not meant for jquery mobile. Use JQM events.

Comment: I worked when I did this:

$page.trigger('create');
$content.find(":jqmData(role=listview)").listview();
$content.find(":jqmData(role=listview)").listview("refresh");

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked When I did this:

```
$page.page();
$page.trigger('create'); // added this one
$content.find(":jqmData(role=listview)").listview();
$content.find(":jqmData(role=listview)").listview("refresh"); // added this one
```